# Echarts: Initial zoom in map type

Tags: javascript, echarts

There is some way to set an initial zoom in chart of map type?

I have this options:

```
m.setOption({
tooltip : {
    trigger: 'item'
},
toolbox: {
    show : true,
    orient : 'vertical',
    x: 'right',
    y: 'center',
    feature : {
        mark : {show: true},
        dataView : {show: true, readOnly: false},
        restore : {show: true},
        saveAsImage : {show: true}
    }
},
asoluteZoom : {start : 90, end : 100},
series : [
    {
        name: 'Name',
        type: 'map',
        mapType: 'world',
        hoverable: false,
        roam:true,
        data : [],
        markPoint : {
            symbolSize: 10,  
            itemStyle: {
                normal: {
                    borderColor: '#87cefa',
                    borderWidth: 1,       
                    label: {
                        show: false
                    }
                },
                emphasis: {
                    borderColor: '#1e90ff',
                    borderWidth: 5,
                    label: {
                        show: false
                    }
                }
            },
            data : [
                {name: "Hello!"},
            ]
        },
        geoCoord: {
            "Hello!":[-4.729075, 37.906475],

        }
    }
]
```

});

I tried with **asoluteZoom** but nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved with: **scaleLimit**
is explained [here](http://echarts.baidu.com/echarts2/doc/option-en.html#line-mark1~series-i(map).scaleLimit)

Comment: This link is broken. The new one is: [link](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-map.scaleLimit).
However, this response was not the right one for me. @anil-agrawal 's response was.

Answer (score 2):

You can do so as below,

```
echartInstance.dispatchAction({
      type: 'dataZoom',
      start: 90,
      end: 100
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **[zoom](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-map.zoom)** property of series object.